# Smallest of three numbers

Tags: python, loops, division, minimum

```
# Using division operator to find 
# minimum of three numbers 
def smallest(x, y, z): 

    if (not (y / x)): # Same as "if (y < x)" 
        return y if (not (y / z)) else z 
    return x if (not (x / z)) else z 

# Driver Code 
if __name__== "__main__": 

    x = 78
    y = 88
    z = 68
    print("Minimum of 3 numbers is", 
                smallest(x, y, z)) 

# This code is contributed 
# by ChitraNayal
```

So I found the above code on the shortest method for finding smallest of three numbers without using min function. I don't quite get the meaning of `not(y/z)` and the rest of the code after that. Does this imply boolean value

Comment: yes `not` results in a Boolean

Comment: Try feeding that expression different data and seeing what results. `12 / 4` vs `4 / 12`, then try `not (12 / 4)` and `not (4 / 12)`.

Comment: so not(y/z) means what? I mean what does y/z imply that might result in some boolean value as a result

Comment: This won't work if negative numbers are involved

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Python 2, dividing two integers uses [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which returns only the "whole" part - i.e., the part left of the decimal point. Thus, if x is smaller than y, x/y will return 0, which evaluates as `False` in a boolean context, so `not(x/y)` is equivalent to asking if x is smaller than y.

Comment: ohh ok!  I am using Python 3.So whenever I was doing the operation ```1/2``` it was resulting in ```0.5``` which doesn't have a boolean type.So replacing ```x/y``` with ```x//y``` will help right?

Comment: @Tanmay yup, for Python 3 you'll have to use `//` to make this snippet work

Answer (score 1):

```
def smallest(x, y, z): 

if (not (y // x)): # Same as "if (y < x)" 
    return y if (not (y // z)) else z 
return x if (not (x // z)) else z 
print(smallest(3,5,7))
```

I think the use of floor division (//) was intended instead of the normal division (/). with this we can have zero as return value of dividing say for example 3//5 and zero is considered a falsy value in python.

Answer (score 0):

While you are into discovering truthiness and integers and want a short non-min implementation, the following will work =)

```
def smallest(x, y, z):
    return ((x,z)[z<x],(y,z)[z<y])[y<x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the shortest method (without using min), an alternative way is to sort an array and get first element.

```
x = 78
y = 88
z = 68

numbers = [x, y, z]
numbers.sort()
print(numbers[0])
```